# Domain of the infinitesimal generator of subordinators

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, semigroups, semigroup-of-operators, levy-processes

Let $(X_t)$ be a subordinator (not killed). Since $(X_t)$ is a non-decreasing Levy process, we have the corresponding infinitesimal generator:
\begin{equation}
Af(x)=\delta f'(x)+\int_{0}^{\infty}(f(x+y)-f(x))\prod(dy),\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
where $\delta\ge0$ is the drift constant and $\prod$ is the jump measure.

Because I got this by applying the general form of infinitesimal generator for Levy processes, the domain is $C^{2}_{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, that is, the function $f$ should satisfy $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Is it possible that (1) holds under the only conditions that $f\ge0$, $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ for $p\ge1$ (without vanishing at infinity)? Any help, advice or reference would be of great help. Thank you very much.